# convert output into csv format Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i created a script that generates this output from a command called command from the script:

```
#Name  age  number       address
mark  23   89756342192   Paris 23=rue
```

and i would convert it to csv format seperated with `;`

```
#Name;age;number;address
mark;23;89756342192;Paris 23=rue
```

the script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate the input file using the command and capture its output
if ! the command | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' > input.txt; then
    echo "Failed to generate input file: $(hset --display --argument pvg 2>&1)"
    echo "####<inc1000>" > output.csv
    echo "#Error: Failed to generate input file" >> output.csv
    echo "####</inc1000>" >> output.csv
    exit 1
fi

# Convert the input file to CSV format
if ! awk 'BEGIN{OFS=";";print "#Resource","Attribute","System","value"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' input.txt > output.csv; then
    echo "Failed to convert input file to CSV format"
    echo "####<inc1000>" > output.csv
    echo "#Error: Failed to convert input file to CSV format" >> output.csv
    echo "####</inc1000>" >> output.csv
    exit 1
fi

# Add start and end markers to output file
echo "####<inc1000>" | cat - output.csv > temp && mv temp output.csv
echo "####</inc1000>" >> output.csv

echo "Conversion successful"
```

i have a problem that the header is generated twice

```
####</inc1000>
#Name;age;number;address
#Name;age;number;address;
mark;23;89756342192;Paris;23=rue
####</inc1000>
```

i would edit it to get the header only once `#Name;age;number;address`

Comment: There is too much "noise" in your question. Read [SO.bash.info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info), skipping the Version information at the top and searching for "How to convert a bad script into a good question". It's likely once you boil this down to your `awk` script you'll figure out your problem on your own. If not, then revise  your post with the reduced problem and post a comment that you have done so. Good luck.

Comment: And I don't see any reason that your whole script can't be reduced to `producer_Command args | awk '{script}'` (maybe 2 `awks`?). Good luck.

Comment: Or `awk -v OFS='";" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' > input.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is all you need

```
{ printf '####<inc1000>\n';my-command | awk -vOFS=\; '{$1=$1}1' || printf 'Error: Failed to generate input file: %s\n' "$(hset --display --argument pvg 2>&1)"; printf '####</inc1000>\n'; } > output.csv
```

Comment: exactly the command give the desired output. thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overthinking this ... the awk will only fail if you have a syntax error - thus only a few times during development. Testing for a conversion failure after that seems highly unnecessary.

And the rest can be condensed to:

```
command | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=";";print "####<inc1000>"}{$1=$1;print}END{print "####</inc1000>"}' > output.csv ||
(echo "Failed to generate input file: $(hset --display --argument pvg 2>&1)"
 echo "####<inc1000>" > output.csv
 echo "#Error: Failed to generate input file" >> output.csv
 echo "####</inc1000>" >> output.csv)
```